# How can I click an element in a drop down menu with RSelenium from a webpage?

Tags: r, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, rselenium

Im trying to change the date from a drop down menu from this website (https://es.investing.com/equities/banco-santander-historical-data) using RSelenium in R to obtain data from previous dates
[image].

However its imposible to inspect those elements and select them, so i can't figure out a solution.

I've tried this

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A quick look at the Network tab of the browser dev tools indicates that the data seems to come from https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/474?start-date=2022-09-26&end-date=2022-10-25&time-frame=Daily&add-missing-rows=false . If you can work with that you don't need Selenium

Comment: Can you re write the link i can't acces to it sorry